# How do I create a templated function can that operate on any std::map that has a string key?

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I want to write a templated case insensitive version of a find function that does something like this:

```
#define TKEYSTR   char*
#define TVALUE    int

typedef std::map<TKEYSTR, TVALUE>  tStrMap; 
auto findKeyIC(const tStrMap& map, const TKEYSTR k)
{
    using TIterator = tStrMap::const_iterator;
    TIterator  it;
    for (it = map.cbegin(); it != map.cend(); map++)
    {
        if (boost::iequals(map.first, k))
            return it;
    }
    return it;
}
```

Goal here is to search a container of key value pairs, where the key is a string (char*, wchar_t*, std::string or std::wstring) and return the matching entry or cend if no match.

How can I define this as a template that handles all the different cases? Can I do it with a single template? Can I do it with 4 explicit templates in some way?

I tried:

```
template<typename _Tvalue>
auto findKeyIC(std::map<char*, _Tvalue>& map, const char* k)
...

template<typename _Tvalue>
auto findKeyIC(std::map<wchar_t*, _Tvalue>& map, const wchar_t* k)
...
```

But it's not allowed as I'm declaring the same template twice.

Finally is it possible to make this work for a wider range of containers than just map? ie any container that has a key which is some form of string?

Thanks

Jules

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore immediately followed by an uppercase char are reserved in C++.

Answer (score 3):

You could flip the problem on its head and create a custom comparison functor that does a case-insensitive comparison. That would make lookup **significantly faster** and easier to use (because you don't have to rely on an external function). It might look something like this.

```
template <typename String>
struct ILess {
  bool operator()(const String &lhs, const String &rhs) const noexcept {
    return boost::ilexicographical_compare(lhs, rhs);
  }
};

template <typename String>
struct IEqualTo {
  bool operator()(const String &lhs, const String &rhs) const noexcept {
    return boost::iequals(lhs, rhs);
  }
};

template <typename String>
struct IHash {
  size_t operator()(const String &str) const noexcept {
    size_t hash = 0;
    for (const auto ch : str) {
      boost::hash_combine(hash, std::toupper(ch));
    }
    return hash;
  }
};

template <typename Key, typename Value>
using IMap = std::map<Key, Value, ILess<Key>>;

template <typename Key, typename Value>
using IUnorderedMap = std::unordered_map<Key, Value, IHash<Key>, IEqualTo<Key>>;
```

Of course, if you need to do case-sensitive and case-insensitive lookups in the same container then this won't work.

Comment: Good solution. I found similar examples of doing it this way elsewhere but as you mention it changes behaviour for all operations, and at the moment I just want the case insensitivity for specific operations.

Comment: What's the 'I' prefix for? Usually I see it on classes serving as interface types, thus having pure virtual functions. But yours are fully implemented classes and not even polymorphic ones, so obviously something else...

Comment: @Aconcagua "I" is for "insensitive". I forgot about that naming convention because I don't use it.

Comment: Ah, could have thought of myself... Well, I don't appreciate that naming convention either and avoid Hungarian notation, too, if not forced to use by some coding guidelines. Solely it's still that common that it is first thing coming into my mind...

Answer (score 1):

You'd define your function as template in parallel to the map's template:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
auto findKey(std::map<Key, ValueType> const& data, Key const& key);
```

For arbitrary containers you can add a template template parameter:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, template<typename, typename> class Container>
auto findKey(Container<Key, Value> const& data, Key const& key);
```

So you could use the function on both ordered and unordered map as well as on your own custom maps.

As is, you are not even limited to string keys, but could use *any* types.

Comment: Thanks, this allowed me to create an answer to the question, though I only realised afterwards that iequals doesn't handle char* etc so I had to specialise.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Aconcagua's answer I wrote the following code that does solve the problem. I had to specialise the char* and wchar* functions as boost iequal only works on strings.

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
auto findKeyIC(std::map<Key, Value> const& map, Key const& key)
{
    using TIterator = std::map<Key, Value>::const_iterator;
    TIterator  it;
    for (it = map.cbegin(); it != map.cend(); it++)
    {
        if (boost::iequals(it->first, key))
            return it;
    }
    return it;
}

template <typename Value>
auto findKeyIC(std::map<char*, Value> const& map, char* const& key)
{
    using TIterator = std::map<char*, Value>::const_iterator;
    TIterator  it;
    for (it = map.cbegin(); it != map.cend(); it++)
    {
        if (_stricmp(it->first, key) == 0)
            return it;
    }
    return it;
}

template <typename Value>
auto findKeyIC(std::map<wchar_t*, Value> const& map, wchar_t* const& key)
{
    using TIterator = std::map<wchar_t*, Value>::const_iterator;
    TIterator  it;
    for (it = map.cbegin(); it != map.cend(); it++)
    {
        if (_wcsicmp(it->first, key) == 0)
            return it;
    }
    return it;
}
```

UPDATE: The code above doesn't quite work, based on suggestion the following is both cleaner and more generic. A bunch more corrections and suggestions from Aconcagua finally resulted in all versions working, I had a lot of trouble getting it to accept a string literal but that's fine too now.

```
template<typename Key>
bool IsKeyEqualI(const Key & str1, const Key & str2)
{
    return boost::iequals(str1, str2);
}

bool IsKeyEqualI(const char *const& str1, const char *const& str2)
{
    return (_stricmp(str1, str2) == 0);
}

bool IsKeyEqualI(const wchar_t *const& str1, const wchar_t *const& str2)
{
    return (_wcsicmp(str1, str2) == 0);
}

template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Reference, template<typename ...> class Container>
auto findKeyIC(Container<Key, Value> & container, Reference const & key)
{
    auto  it = container.begin();
    for (; it != container.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (IsKeyEqualI(it->first, key))
            return it;
    }
    return it;
}
```

Comment: You could still combine that with a template template parameter to accept arbitrary mapping types...

Comment: I've just been working on that but hit a problem where it's not recognising my template, This is what I tried but when I invoke it I get errors:

template <typename Value, template<typename, typename> class Container>
auto findKeyIC(Container<wchar_t*, Value> const& container, wchar_t* const& key)

Comment: I wouldn't specialise the entire function. Instead I'd have a separate comparison function of which you have specialisations. You'd duplicate fare less code that way.

Comment: Apart from, you can simplify your code a bit: `auto it = map.begin(); for(; it != end; ++it) { }`, avoiding having to specify the type explicitly. (Side note: on a const map, begin and cbegin are all the same, there's only a difference on non-const maps.)

Comment: I see... At very first, all you need is separate comparison functions. Simplest is having overloads instead of template specialisations: `bool equalsCI(char const* x, char const* y); bool equalsCI(wchar_t const* x, wchar_t const* y); bool equals(std::string const& x, std::string const& y);`

Comment: Then we get a problem with the pointer specialisations: `template <typename Key, typename Value, template<typename, typename> class Container>
auto findKey(Container<Key, Value> const& data, Key const& key)` deduces to `findKey(std::map<char*, ...>, char * const&)`, resulting in the pointer being const, not the data pointed to!

Comment: I think the problem may be due to the fact that std::map template actually takes 4 arguments. I get error: could not deduce template argument for 'const Container<Key,Value> &' from 'std::map<wchar_t *,PaHostApiTypeId,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'

Comment: To get that right, we unfortunately need another overload: `template <typename Key, typename Value, template<typename, typename> class Container>
auto findKey(Container<Key*, Value> const& data, Key const* key)`. Note the difference: this one will deduce second parameter to `char const*` vs. `char * const` before.

Comment: With which standard version are you compiling with? Not fully sure, but instantiating templates expecting less parameters with others having more, but defaulting ones, is only possible since C++17 (maybe C++14?). If you have a compiler defaulting to older standard (or set to use older standard via compiler flags), you'll need to add these additional template parameters.

Comment: You might try with `<typename ...>` instead of instead of `<typename, typename>` as template template parameters. Both clang and GCC (both with -std=c++11) accept, at least. And you can avoid necessity for two overloads if you give the lookup parameter its own type. So in total: `template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Reference, template<typename ...> class Container> auto findKey(Container<Key, Value> const& data, Reference const& key)` This will deduce key to `char const* const&` for string literals, while the map parameter can remain `char*`.

Comment: Oh, side note: standard map will compare pointer values for `char*` and `wchar_t*`, *not* the strings themselves. So you'd need to add your custom comparator anyway! Try this to see: `std::map<char*, int> m; char h1[] = "h"; char h2[] = "h"; m[h1] = 10; m[h2] = 12; std::cout << m.size() << std::endl;`

Comment: @Aconcagua I have updated the answer above with a version of the code that seemed to work. I'm sticking with C++11 for now, so I needed the ... and various other tweaks. Your comments plus removing all the const and then adding them back in bit by bit got me the finally answer. Thank-you so much for your patience and insights.